# Pandas extract multicharacter regex

Tags: python, string, pandas

I would like to extract an expression each time it occurs in an element of a Pandas DataFrame as an array but get an error every time I use a multiple character expression.  Why am I getting this error?  How do I make the extraction work as expected?

## MWE

```
import pandas as pd

wiki = ["In theoretical computer the like operations.",
    "The a filter.",
    "In the.",
    "the dog is the one",
    "See below for details."
]
wiki

x = pd.DataFrame(wiki, columns = ['wiki'])
x
```

### Error for multicharacter expression

```
x.wiki.str.extractall('(the)')

## x.wiki.str.extractall('(the)')
## Traceback (most recent call last):
## 
##   File "<ipython-input-7-ca5d102219f3>", line 1, in <module>
##     x.wiki.str.extractall('(the)')
## 
##   File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 1621, in extractall
##     return str_extractall(self._orig, pat, flags=flags)
## 
##   File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 716, in str_extractall
##     result = DataFrame(match_list, index, columns)
## 
##   File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 263, in __init__
##     arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
## 
##   File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5352, in _to_arrays
##     dtype=dtype)
## 
##   File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5431, in _list_to_arrays
##     coerce_float=coerce_float)
## 
##   File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.1Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5489, in _convert_object_array
##     'columns' % (len(columns), len(content)))
## 
## AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

### As expected single character expression

```
x.wiki.str.extractall('(t)')

## x.wiki.str.extractall('(t)')
## Out[8]: 
##          0
##   match   
## 0 0      t
##   1      t
##   2      t
##   3      t
##   4      t
## 1 0      t
## 2 0      t
## 3 0      t
##   1      t
## 4 0      t
```

### I was expecting this:

```
  match   
0 0      the
  1      the
2 0      the
3 0      the
  1      the
```

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: @MaxU '0.18.1' Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extractall()` method has a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13382) which should be fixed in pandas 0.18.2, which should be released pretty soon, so let's be patient or risk a little bit and use a [beta 0.18.2 version](http://pandas.pydata.org/) ... ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I this was bugging me (no pun intended) for about 30 minutes.

Comment: @TylerRinker, yeah, bug happens. ;) But still, i have a huge respect to the pandas team - they are doing really a __great__ job

Comment: Oh yeah definitely.  I am a new Python user from R and have really enjoyed Pandas.